# Sum time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df with columns date, employee and event. 'Event' have value [1,3,5] if someone exit or [0,2,4] if someone entries. 'Employee' it's a private number for each employee. That's a head of df:

```
   employee  event  registration                date
0         4      1             1 2010-10-18 18:11:00
1        17      1             1 2010-10-18 18:15:00
2         6      0             1 2010-10-19 06:28:00
3         8      0             0 2010-10-19 07:04:00
4        15      0             1 2010-10-19 07:34:00
```

I sorted df and I have value from one month [year and month are my variables].

```
df = df.where(df['date'].dt.year == year).dropna()
df = df.where(df['date'].dt.month== month).dropna()
```

I want to create df which shows me sum of time in work for each employee.
Employees come in and come out at the same day and they could do it a few times in each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `groupby` where get difference by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) with `sum`:

```
year = 2010
month = 10

df = df[(df['date'].dt.year == year) & (df['date'].dt.month== month)]
```

More general solution is add to `groupby` `year` and `month`:

```
df =df['date'].groupby([df['employee'],
                        df['event'], 
                        df['date'].rename('year').dt.year, 
                        df['date'].rename('month').dt.month]).apply(lambda x: x.diff().sum())
```

Comment: Yeah I need groupby, but not by df['event']. Event 0 means come in, event 1 means come out. But after small change it's works fine.